# comic reader not get directory from sd card

Tags: android, android-mapview

i am using this code links https://github.com/Juanvvc/ComicViewer
for study of comic reader . but when i am using it and debug. i got a message like as "please select a directory of comix" and when i clicked on "ok" button ,i didn't get any list of directory so i can select any directory for comic display.

please help me , 
thank you

Comment: i am using this code . but not get images in imageview . String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
      imgFile = new File( root_sd + "/Pictures/bremen.map" ) ;       

        MapView mapView = new MapView(this);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMapFile(imgFile);
        setContentView(mapView);
        System.out.println("This is ok");
        } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println("run time error is occure "+e.getMessage()); }

Comment: What you are trying to do is plain wrong.MapView was not made for the purpose of showing images

Comment: ohh Really,  is it possible in IMAGEVIEW .

Comment: first of all your String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(); is wrong as it should be String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

Comment: But i think your problem is broader than that,i don't know about mapsForge but if it is similar to google mapview you will not be able to use more than one in your activity,which invalidates the whole point of how you want to use it.Also you are using it for a task it was not made for..You should really rethink about how to implement what you want to achieve

Comment: Thank you , i have changed it but again got runtime error.  this is my modify code.try { setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
      imgFile = new File( root_sd + "/Pictures/rahul1.jpg" ) ;       
 MapView mapView = new MapView(this);
    mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMapFile(imgFile);
        setContentView(mapView);
        System.out.println("This is ok");
        } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println("run time error is occure "+e.getMessage()); }

Comment: I will use to Imageview display image from sd-card and do activity like mapview . i have successed in zoom in - zoom out but i am not creating a code so user can zoom with TWO-FINGER movement . is it possible in  imageview.

Comment: user: come to point u r struggling ..understand.. the problem for fresher

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you need is using a [viewpager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) probably,where you load all your images,and you will be able to scroll between them.You should take a look at [horizontal swiping between views](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)
You could use [android Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) but that has been deprecated,so it is not wise to use it anymore.
With regards to the zoom and pinch ability,you must implement that by yourself.[One finger zoom](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/) could be a good start to learn.
Also your question was really broad,you should improve,by first documenting yourself on the topic,and ask here ONLY when you have problems with code.You showed no sign of research,nor did show any code.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  i am using .jar file from "mapsforge" and all the images are in SD-CARD/pictures/   ..

Comment: Dear sokie,  I have totally covered with this problem. and i am searching a EXPERT who help me .  i want to create a imagereader who read all the images from a folder located in sd-card/pictures/ . this is same as adobe reader . please help me . i am waiting for your kindly response. thanks